# Create array from range 11AA to 99ZZ

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I don't know how to make array from range 11AA to 99ZZ. Is it possible to do it in Ruby?

I want this array:

```
['11AA', '11AB', '11AC',..., '99ZX', '99ZY', '99ZZ']
```

Comment: Unstated assumption: you want your letter-iteration to use uppercase letters from the English alphabet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
('11AA'..'99ZZ').to_a
```

Comment: That's it. Actually I tried it but without single quote signs: `(11AA..99ZZ).to_a`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo code would be:

```
for i '1' to '9'
 for j '1' to '9'
  for k 'A' to 'Z'
   for l 'A' to 'Z'
    insert_in_array(i+j+k+l);
```

of course the values are stored as strings, with double "" not''.This is a pseudo code, it can be applied in any programming language.

Comment: +1, nice to know this solution for implementing in other languages.

Comment: Иван, you're being too nice to him :)